How to connect a microsoft SQL Server database to Open Data Discovery (odd-odd-platform)?
I'm trying to connect my SQL Server database to the Open Data Discovery (ODD) platform. Here are the steps I've followed so far:

I deployed a SQL Server database using Azure Data Studio by following this guide.

I created the database:
`CREATE DATABASE BikeStores;

I created the tables and loaded the data according to this tutorial.

I checked the IP and port with the following query:`


I verified the connection to the database using Python:


import pyodbc

# Connection parameters
server = 'localhost'
database = 'BikeStores'
username = 'sa'
password = 'my_password'

# Connection string
conn_str = (
    f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};'
    f'SERVER={server};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'UID={username};'
    f'PWD={password}'
)

try:
    # Connect to the database
    with pyodbc.connect(conn_str) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        
        # Query to get table names
        query = """
        SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
        """
        cursor.execute(query)
        
        # Fetch the data
        tables = cursor.fetchall()
        
        # Output the table names
        for table in tables:
            schema, name = table
            print(f'{schema}.{name}')

except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print(f'Connection error: {e}')


The output was:


Following the ODD setup guide, I cloned the ODD Platform repository:

git clone https://github.com/opendatadiscovery/odd-platform
cd odd-platform
docker-compose -f docker/demo.yaml up -d odd-platform-enricher

I opened the ODD interface at http://localhost:8080/management/datasources, then added a collector at http://localhost:8080/management/collectors:



I copied the token and pasted it into the odd-platform/docker/config/collector_config.yaml file as follows:



I started the collector with the following command:

docker-compose -f docker/demo.yaml up -d odd-collector 

Tried restarting the collector several times:

docker-compose -f docker/demo.yaml restart odd-collector
Problem:
The ODD Platform does not detect the connected database, and the data is not loading. What steps did I miss or do incorrectly?

Think about it, what will host: 127.0.0.1 point to in a docker environment

I also tried the local address 192.168.1.7 , but it didn't help

i think you need host.docker.internal or perhaps  172.17.0.1

From a networking perspective Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs, with localhost, 127.0.0.1 and ::1 all referring to themselves. If you want a process in a Docker container to communicate with a service running on the Docker host have you tried using host.docker.internal instead?

Thank you for your help! I resolved my issue by changing the IP address (172.18.0.1) and updating the collector_config.yaml file. It really worked!

Doesn't host.docker.internal work? It's more natural address to use

I resolved my issue by changing the IP address (172.18.0.1)

and updating the collector_config.yaml file.

